# can the Continued Busines Justification for a project change in Prince2

Tags: prince2

We all know that in Prince2,  If a project is no longer justified it should be stopped. That is,  The justification for the project should remain valid. However, can the  **Continued Busines Justification** for a project change in Prince2? or must it remain the same throughout the project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course the business reasons to do a project might change. It might become more interesting to do a project, or less... It all depends on the environment you're in:

- the strategy of the department or larger organization might change, e.g. it's no longer our core business; or new responsibilities make the need for the new system even more important.
- there is a change in legislation that forces us to do more; or makes the desired benefits less likely...
- the competition has launched a similar product or service, and is now claiming a part of the market you were hoping for.

It's inherent to a project that it involves change, so also the business rational might change. As long as there still is a business justification, it's fine. PRINCE2 does not state it should be fixed! But rather it should be reviewed regularly, and verified if it still makes sense to do/continue the project.